# Problema de dependencia com o Maven (plugin m2) no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Sou novo em desenvolvimento java e não tenho muito conhecimento em Maven. O Pouco que aprendi foi através de pesquisas e tutoriais na internet, e agora estou enfrentando um problema que me parece ser relacionado a configurações e não sei como resolver.

Vamos lá. Estou usando o Maven (EMBEDDED version 3.2.1 / 1.5.1.50109-1819) que vem junto com o Eclipse Juno para gerenciar minhas dependências. Junto com eles, utilizo também o plugin jBoss Tools para enviar minha aplicação para o Openshift. Até ai tudo bem.

Estou enfrentando problemas com meu tomcat 8 no openshift e a partir de alguns logs e pesquisas, pude constatar que o problema é aparentemente um bug da versão 
5.0.8 do mysql-connector-java.jar contido em meu projeto. Sendo assim, fui no Maven Repository para pegar a versão mais recente do mysql-connector-java e muda-la no meu arquivo pom.xml.

De

`<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8</version>
        </dependency>`

para

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
```

Ao salvar o pom.xml após fazer a mudança da versão 5.0.8 para a 5.1.38 do mysql-connector-java, o Maven parece não copiar o arquivo mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar para a pasta WEB-INF/lib do meu projeto local, mas quando dou um Maven build com o goal clean install, o Maven faz a build com sucesso, e na que na pasta target/MeuApp.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib está tanto o mysql-connector-java.5.0.8-bin.jar quanto o mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar. O que pode estar acontecendo? O fluxo correto do Maven ao mudar a versão de uma dependência no arquivo pom.xml não é baixa-la e salva-la na pasta WEB-INF/lib do aplicativo local e deletar a versão anterior? Por favor, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda =)